# control.parent and control.HasChildren

Tags: c#, parent

I was going through some c# code and saw code like eg

```
if (c.HasChildren)
```

..

```
if (c.parent is NumericUpDown)
```

Can anybody tell me that what are they and what`s their use.

Thanks

Comment: What is `c`? Probably a Control? That code is pure english... and I think is obviously clear what they mean :)

Comment: `if (c.HasChildren)` tells you if `c` has any child. And `if (c.parent is NumericUpDown)` tells you if the parent of `c` is of type `NumericUpDow`

Answer (score 1):

c is some type of gui component. Its asking if the control has controls within it (hasChildren)

Its then asking if the control that `c` is in is a NumericUpDown control. (the parent of the c control)

Answer (score 1):

c is a visual elements of your page and is build up logically.

You will have your main form.
This form will have several panels or controls as children, all the way down to your buttons and labels.

So if you do `.HasChildren` you just check if the control has any elements inside. Probably when they have been added dynamically.

`.Parent` is the method to get the containing control of your current. It enables you to ask it's properties or modify it.